# sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO address VALUES (:f_name, : l_name, :address, :city, :zipcode)",
            {
                'f_name': f_name.get(),
                'l_name': l_name.get(),
                'address': address.get(),
                'city': city.get(),
                'state': state.get(),
                'zipcode': zipcode.get()
            })
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies at `: l_name,`, you have a space after the `:` which causes your error.

### How it currently looks

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO address VALUES (:f_name, : l_name, :address, :city, :zipcode)",
```

### How it should look

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO address VALUES (:f_name, :l_name, :address, :city, :zipcode)",
```

Comment: Thanks That was it